# How to group by one column and display a list in another column- How do you execute in SparkSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one Sales table: the attributes are:

1. date
2. time
3. company name
4. Item
5. Price
6. Payment mode

I want to group by the company name and list the payment modes received by that company.

```
Company Name     Payment mode
1.LG             Cash,debit,credit
2.Sabre          debit,credit
```

Tried executing the following:

```
select company name,payment mode from sales group by company name
```

Comment: What dbms are you using? SQL-Server?

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: How do execute this in a sparkSQL? @ Felix Pamittan

Comment: @FelixPamittan how do you execute this in SparkSQL -I am using python.Please suggest